# oci_pconnect(): ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, ora-12545

I am unable to connect to sql from within the docker container. Bashing into one of the containers and doing `sqlplus` gives me this error:

`ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

However, using SQL Developer outside the container allows me to log into the same database with same credentials without any problem. Please note that the problem might be related to the configuration of docker because same code is working fine on another machine.